# Detecting location of any text in an image in opencv using c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

http://www.2d3dfloorplans.com/wp-content/themes/default/images/2dfloorplans_1.jpg is my input image. I would like to remove texts from this image. (For ex. Bedroom, 11'X12', Closet...). ***Note: I want to remove automatically. Not manually.(When I run my code. Texts will be removed. I won't remove manually).***

Comment: can you add more details? Perhaps what code you've used so far and what your ideal solution looks like?

Comment: pastebin.com/5ZeMvm2C is my header file and http://pastebin.com/gqJ5RpBU is my main file. My project detects walls in a 2d floor plan. However When I detect walls. I also detect texs(Like Bedroom or Closet...) as walls. This is an unwanted situation for me. Therefore. I want to remove texts from floor plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know all the possible text variations, and there not too many of them, (individual words can be split) then you can detect them using template matching technique. Once a word is detected you can overlay it's region with a background color.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

suggested code stucture:

```
program/
  samples/
    sample1.png # image with a "Bedroom" text
    sample2.png # rotated image with "Bedroom" text
    sample3.png # ...
    sample4.png # etc
  src/
    main.cpp
  readme.txt
  makefile
```

main reads image from argv and applies each template from samples folder to it. Once text is found it then uses some logic to overlay the occupied region.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run an OCR algorithm on the images and delete the regions detected by the OCR algorithm.